# Error while importing pydelicious module

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am receiving this error while importing get_popular function of pydelicious module.

The code is :

```
import pydelicious
pydelicious.get_popular(tag = 'programming')
```

and the error:

```
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/temp2/Pydelicious.py", line 2, in <module>
pydelicious.get_popular(tag = 'programming')
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 985, in get_popular
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 969, in getrss
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 447, in dlcs_rss_request


File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 227, in http_request
pydelicious.PyDeliciousException: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Please provide a possible solution or is there anything I'm doing differently.

Comment: `HTTP Error 404: Not Found` so looks like you may want to configure some endpoint or some such somewhere?

Comment: Actually looks like this package was [last updated in 2010](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydelicious/0.6), so it's probably using some older/deprecated version of the API.